# Docker Build file Failed

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run my docker image which was custom build as per our requirement. It was working well on most of machines but a error is thrown on one machine and the error is.

````
SpecsConfigurationConflictError: Requested specs conflict with configured specs.
 requested specs:
   - h5py=2.7
   - numba=0.38
 pinned specs:
   - python=3.7
Use 'conda config --show-sources' to look for 'pinned_specs' and 'track_features'
configuration parameters.  Pinned specs may also be defined in the file
/opt/conda/conda-meta/pinned.


ERROR: Service 'jupyterlab' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c conda install --quiet --yes     'conda-forge::blas=*=openblas'     'ipywidgets=7.4*'     'pandas=0.23*'     'numexpr=2.6*'     'matplotlib=2.2*'     'scipy=1.1*'     'seaborn=0.9*'     'scikit-learn=0.20*'     'scikit-image=0.14*'     'sympy=1.1*'     'cython=0.28*'     'patsy=0.5*'     'statsmodels=0.9*'     'cloudpickle=0.5*'     'dill=0.2*'     'numba=0.38*'     'bokeh=0.13*'     'sqlalchemy=1.2*'     'hdf5=1.10*'     'h5py=2.7*'     'vincent=0.4.*'     'beautifulsoup4=4.6.*'     'protobuf=3.*'     'xlrd'  &&     conda remove --quiet --yes --force qt pyqt &&     conda clean -tipsy &&     jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension --sys-prefix &&     jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@^0.38.1 &&     jupyter labextension install jupyterlab_bokeh@0.6.3 &&     jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/plotly-extension &&     jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/toc &&     jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/google-drive &&     jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-sidecar &&     npm cache clean --force &&     rm -rf $CONDA_DIR/share/jupyter/lab/staging &&     rm -rf /home/$NB_USER/.cache/yarn &&     rm -rf /home/$NB_USER/.node-gyp &&     fix-permissions $CONDA_DIR &&     fix-permissions /home/$NB_USER' returned a non-zero code: 1```

Couldn't figure out what's going wrong. any help is appreciated.
````

Comment: You must provide t us he Dockerfile so we can help you..

Comment: I just figured out thanks for your time. The h5py library which I am trying to import is deprecyated